# Embedding of parallelizable closed smooth manifold

Tags: differential-topology

It seems that any closed parallelizable smooth $n$-manifold can be immersed in the $(n+1)$-dimensional Euclidean space (compared to the general $(2n-1)$-dimensional case). Is there any analogous result for embedding?

Comment: All 3--manifolds are parallelisable but most of them do not embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Are you looking for a linear bound with constant less than 2, say?

Comment: Yes.All I am asking is whether we can improve on the dim 2n (from Whitney embedding theorem) in case of parallelizable manifolds.

Comment: Orientable $n>1$-manifolds can always be embedded in $(2n-1)$-dimensional space, but surely you can do better than this under the parallelizability assumption.

Comment: To my knowledge it is still an open conjecture, that a parallelisable $n$-manifold embeds in Euclidean space of dimension approximatively $3n/2.$